# Hide a tabpanel in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

```
Ext.define('rgpd.view.Viewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
    layout: 'border',
    requires: [
        'rgpd.view.Entity1.View',
        'rgpd.view.Entity2.View',
    ],
    items: [{
        xtype: 'tabpanel',
        id: 'tabpanel1',
        region: 'center',
        tabPosition: 'left',
        titleRotation: 0,
        tabRotation: 0,
        padding: 0,
        margin: 0,
        split: true,
        header: {
            layout: {
                align: 'stretchmax'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'MAIN',
                flex: 0
            },
            glyph: 124,
            items: []
        },
        items: [{
                xtype: 'entity1xtype',
                textAlign: 'right',
                flex: 1,
            },
            {
                xtype: 'entity2xtype',
                textAlign: 'right',
                flex: 1,
            },
        ],
    }]
});
```

I have something like below screenshot the left side menu which allows me to switch between my different views. But there is a large number of entity and I want to be able to wrap/unwrap it with a button or something like that.

---

[image: this]

Comment: exactly what you need? do you want to hide left side menu or something else. Provide more explanation for this .

Answer (score 0):

Make your `TabPanel` collapsible

Just add this code to `TabPanel` config

```
{
    collapsible: true,
    hideCollapseTool: true,
    split:true
}
```

And if you want the splitter to be smaller add this config too

```
collapseMode: "mini"
```